# How to install Windows 8 using Windows 8 System Builder

Tags: windows-8

On my personal computer, I inserted Windows 8 System Builder disc and ran through entire installation process. At the end, it reboots and sends me through the entire install process again.

How do I avoid this endless loop?

I tried removing the disc just before the reboot but then I get a message saying that my PC needs repair because the "digital signature of `winload.exe` cannot be verified".

Is some repair required?

Answer (score 0):

Secure boot in the bios needs to be disabled during installation of W8, enable it after install and setup of user accounts is complete, your manufacturer should have very specific instructions for install W8 on your PC, it is not as easy as it use to be, the game has changed completely.

"I tried removing the disc just before the reboot"  This is the correct procedure when you have the dvd drive set as first boot device, otherwise you will keep booting from the disc.

Here are the [lengthy and very specific instructions for HP laptops](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c03451712&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en), I am sure other makes are similar, you should review your PC makers support pages for specific instructions about Windows 8 upgrades on their hardware.

Comment: On the subject of the DVD as the first boot device, Windows installation DVDs display a 'press any key to boot from this DVD'. If nothing is pressed, it should skip to the next boot device.

Comment: In a perfect world you are correct, how could installation start all over? because the message was skipped for unknown reasons, which I have seen plenty of times with Windows.

Comment: Even if I had an HP (and I don't) the HP instructions tell the me what to do before executing the the install. As I can't go back in time, I seem to be dead in the water.